# Possible to send an image from Preview app to Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: preview, adobe-photoshop

I would like to have a button or configurable keyboard shortcut to send the image in active Preview app to Adobe Photoshop.

It will also be useful if I can specify which version of Photoshop to open with.

Does anyone know how?

Using OS X Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation isn't a keyboard shortcut, but an easy way to send files between applications. Simply grab your file's icon at the title bar (proxy icon) and drop it on the app's dock icon (doesn't matter if the application is closed or open):

[image: Dragging file...]

Subsequently your app will open (launch if the app is closed) and open the given image.

[image: Image open]

It works on all sorts of apps with all sorts of files. If you have several versions of Photoshop, simply drag it to the one you please. Hope it's useful!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this.

For some reason I can't seem to get hold of the proxy icon with my trackpad (tap and drag). The entire window keeps moving. I have a mouse connected as well and dragging the proxy icon works with it.

Comment: That proxy icon can be quite small and has to be grabbed precisely -- or, as you say, you just end up moving the window. Maybe the mouse is just a little easier to control than the trackpad?

Also, I'd be careful to close the file from Preview as soon as you open it in Photoshop. Preview will auto-save under Lion so you could get file conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

If Photoshop is in your Dock, you can drag the Proxy icon (the small document icon that appears next to the document name in the title bar) and drop it on the Photoshop icon in your Dock (or, if you have multiple versions of Photoshop in your Dock, drop it on the one you want).

[image]

Comment: If this is too many motions, an Automator/AppleScript solution can be written, but this is simplest, using out-of-the-box features of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Use the proxy icon, drag and drop it on Photoshop icon in dock]

Full instructions here
http://osxandioshelp.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Send-Image-from-Preview-to-Photoshop.jpg

It would be cool if we have an icon or contextual menu to do that.